# Is there any pragma to add a directory into include/library search path

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I know that I can use this pragma to add a library into a project:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_calib3d246d.lib")
```

This allow me to create a include file and when it is added to a project, it includes all libraries to that project (in this case, opencv libraries).

Is there any other #pragma that I can use to set the include path or library search path?

I am suing visual studio 2012.

Comment: Even if you could: Why would you want your code to be this inflexible? You force any other coders on the project to have their include and library search paths exactly like you have.

Comment: @arne: I hope I can use environment variable as part of this to solve the problem that you indicate. But mainly I want this for testing, when I am creating a new project to test a sample code, I don't want to go and set it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it on a file by file basis:  [include_alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbeh5h91.aspx).  Other than that, I don't think so.